# Как создать GTK+ проект в QtCreator-e в ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, qtcreator, gtk+

*В общем решил почитать **Foundations of GTK+ Development**  там мне библиотека **GLib** нужна , но для хорошего понимания решил пробежаться по книге "через код"*

Установил библиотеку **GTK+**

```
       comp@comp0:~$ sudo apt-cache search GTK+  //для поиска правильного названия
       comp@comp0:~$ sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-dev // ставим как "либу" так и пакет разработчика
```

После ввёл стандартный хелоу верод из книги. Вот код:

**GTK_hw.pro**

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += gtk
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.c

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lgtk-3

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/gtk-3.0
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/gtk-3.0

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/glib-2.0
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include/


unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lpango-1.0

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/pango-1.0
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/pango-1.0

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lcairo

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/cairo
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/cairo

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -latk-1.0

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/atk-1.0
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/atk-1.0
```

Замете как много библиотек и в каком "множестве" требуется подключать
*При компиляции creator ненаходил файл (к примеру atk.h) искал через консоль `locate atk.h` и в директорих  `/usr/include/` либо `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`*

**main.c**

```
#include <gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    /* Initialize GTK+ and all of its supporting libraries. */
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
    /* Create a new window, give it a title and display it to the user. */
    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Hello World");
    gtk_widget_show (window);
    /* Hand control over to the main loop. */
    gtk_main ();
    return 0;
}
```

Выводит мне три ошибки

```
:-1: ошибка: main.o: undefined reference to symbol 'g_type_check_instance_cast'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0:-1: ошибка: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
:-1: ошибка: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 0):

Подсмотрел [на сайте ответ :3](https://www.lucidarme.me/gtk-and-qt-creator/)

Надо изменить текст в заголовочном файле :

**GTK_hw.pro**

```
# Disable Qt core and Qt Graphical user interface (don't use Qt)
QT      -= core
QT      -= gui

# Name of the target (executable file)
TARGET      = gtk_test

# This is a console application
CONFIG      += console
CONFIG      -= app_bundle

# This is an application
TEMPLATE    = app


# Sources files
SOURCES     += main.c

# GTK+ library
unix: CONFIG    += link_pkgconfig
unix: PKGCONFIG += gtk+-3.0
```

**main.c** остаётся прежним. *Для удобства вставлю его здесь*

```
#include <gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    /* Initialize GTK+ and all of its supporting libraries. */
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
    /* Create a new window, give it a title and display it to the user. */
    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Hello World");
    gtk_widget_show (window);
    /* Hand control over to the main loop. */
    gtk_main ();
    return 0;
}
```

Вот результат :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]